# Win Form Tab Control Page header layout

Tags: c#

Simple question I hope....  I have a Win Form with a Tab Control and 12 tabs.  When I added the eight table (and higher), the scroll bar in the tab header appears and you have to scroll with that control to view the extra tabs.  How can you change the layout so that the tabs all show, without the scroll bar?  Is it possible to have them appear "stacked" or "Multiline"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Multiline` property to `true`.

```
tabControl1.Multiline = true;
```

As simple as that.

Comment: Well, that was it.   Not sure how I missed it.  I was even looking for "Multiline."  Thanks much.   Can we justify the tabs also?

Comment: There is a `SizeMode` with the values `Normal`, `FillToRight` and `Fixed`.

Comment: Thanks much!   That is what I was looking for!  Have a good week!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've seen what you're describing before unless for some reason I've accidentally haven't set the proper width of the control.  Have you tried setting the width to something less than the width of the area you're describing....and maybe make sure to use a pixel value vs. a percentage just to narrow it down perhaps.